# how do i build openthread stack for thread leader role?

Tags: openthread

I am new to openthread. I am trying to build thread leader and end devices.
End devices should not have routing capability. I built the thread stack for nxp target with `Border_ROUTER=1`. Under the output directory there are 4 binaries (ot-cli-ftd  ot-cli-mtd  ot-ncp-ftd  ot-ncp-mtd  ot-ncp-radio). I would like to know which binary can be placed on thread leader and end device .
procedure followed:

```
./configure --enable-commissioner 
make
make -f examples/Makefile-kw41z BORDER_ROUTER=1
```

If my procedure is wrong (I'm pretty sure it is) how do I build for thread leader and end device? What are switches to be used when I make?

Answer (score 1):

All Thread Routers support the Leader role. The Full Thread Device (FTD) builds support the Router and Leader roles. The FTD binaries are generated using the default build configuration - no need to specify any additional build parameters.